# A polynomial map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$ mapping the positive orthant onto $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

> **Question:** Is there a polynomial map from $\Bbb R^n$  to $\Bbb R^n$ under which the image of the positive orthant (the set of points with all coordinates positive) is all of $\Bbb R^n$ ?

Some observations:

My intuition is that the answer must be 'no'... but I confess my intuition for this sort of geometric problem is not very well-developed.

Of course it is relatively easy to show that the answer is 'no' when $n=1$.  (In fact it seems like a nice homework problem for some calculus students.)  But I can't seem to get any traction for $n>1$.

This feels like the sort of thing that should have an easy proof, but then I remember feeling that way the first time I saw the Jacobian conjecture... now I'm wary of statements about polynomial maps of $\Bbb R^n$ !

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38868/vector-valued-functions for some apparently minimal degree maps when n>1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The map $z\in\mathbb C\mapsto z^4\in\mathbb C$, when written out in coordinates, is a polynomial map which sends the *closed* first quadrant to the whole of $\mathbb R^2$---and by considering cartesian products you get the same for $\mathbb R^{2n}=\mathbb C^n$.

**Later:** as observed in a comment by [Charles](https://mathoverflow.net/users/622/charles-siegel), this can be turned into a solution for the *open* quadrant by composing with a translation, as in $z\in\mathbb C\mapsto (z-z_0)^4\in\mathbb C$ with $z_0$ in the open first quadrant.

Comment: This yields maps for all even dimensions.  Is there a simple answer to the odd-dimensional case?

Comment: Yes, because you can use this trick for any pair of coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, regardless of the parity of $n$, and then compose until positivity has been eliminated for all coordinates.

Comment: The question asks about the *open* orthant, not the closed one!

Comment: Then take $(z-z_0)^4$ and it should be patched, when $z_0$ is in the open first orthant.

Comment: As Charles suggests, the open orthant is equivalent to the closed orthant for this question, because you can compose with translation.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed, this is a great answer!  (Now I wonder what can be said about the form of such polynomial maps.)